# Resources to learn about Quantum Monte Carlo?

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics

This is a very, very broad question, but I've recently become interested with [Quantum Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Monte_Carlo) (QMC) and other numerical techniques in physics and computational physics, though my undergraduate institution doesn't offer any courses in this field.

I was wondering if anyone had any resources or books to get started? I guess I'm effectively asking how to get starting in numerical methods in many body physics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off starting with a book or books on computational physics. There are several free books in PDF format that covers computation physics and features many programs in python or another language. These books are fairly recent and covers many aspects of numerical calculations in addition to the physics of the problems. The options that I'm aware of are

Computational Physics Problem Solving with Computers
Enlarged eTextBook Python 3rd Edition
RUBIN H. LANDAU
Oregon State University
MANUEL JOSE ́ PA ́EZ
University of Antioquia
CRISTIAN C. BORDEIANU
University of Bucharest
Video Production by Sally Haerer
Applets: P ́aez CP Group, Hans Kowallik, David Wolf & Bert Laubsch

Computational Physics With Python
 Dr. Eric Ayars California State University, Chico

A google search on Computational Physics will pop up many more references. Also, if you are still particularly interested in Quantum Monte Carlo a google search on that returns many hits as well. You may be better at determining what you want yourself than references from others.